# Android downloading via Retrofit VS Download Manager

Tags: android, download, retrofit, download-manager

I need to download an mp3 file from a server, and I was wondering which was the best way to do it. What are the differences between downloading via Retrofit 2 and via the download manage? The file I want to download is a song which length can vary.

I know the retrofit library offers @Streaming annotations and async' downloads, so I was wondering which one should I use?  Here is a link to the Retrofit download [how to link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-download-files-from-server)

Tanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this library https://github.com/lingochamp/FileDownloader
Or if you prefer the reactive way : https://github.com/esafirm/RxDownloader

Comment: Doesnt answer the question, but these are indeed nice libraries, I will take a look at them. Thanks